# How to have the form refresh after a return false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here is the situation:

I have a JavaScript that checks to see if the email address is valid or not. So when the email address isn't valid, it would prompt a message stating that the email is not valid. After the user clicks OK, nothing happens.

```
function FF_OnBeforeSave() {     
    var x = document.getElementById('Mailing_List__c.Name');
    var atpos=x.value.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.value.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Please Enter a Valid Email Address");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

What I'm expecting is that form is active regardless.

Comment: What do you mean the form is "active"? Can you speak a bit more to what you're expecting when the user hits "OK". Also, where's this logic that handles the result of "FF_OnBeforeSave", can you show us that?

Comment: How you are handling `FF_OnBeforeSave`? You can refresh the form if you are calling this function from JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried `<input type="email">`?

Comment: `alert` will simply show a browser alert message, which can be dismissed by the user. There's no callback, so nothing will happen after the user hits "OK". If you want something else to happen when an invalid email is provided you'll have to handle that wherever you're calling the validation method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form can have many input fields. If a user enters an invalid email, you are showing an alert. After seeing that alert, user will be able to edit the email and submit again. You can even highlight the email field or use some other techniques to show the validation.

If you use

```
<input type="email">
```

for the email field, you don't have to write a method to validate it. It will automatically validate it.

If you refresh the form, all the input values will be cleared. Then the user has to input all the fields again. That will be a bad experience for the user.

If you want to clear all the values, you can have a button to reset the values in the form. Please refer to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_reset.asp

Answer (score 0):

```js
function FF_OnBeforeSave() {
  var x = document.getElementById('email');
  var atpos = x.value.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = x.value.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
    alert("Please Enter a Valid Email Address");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return FF_OnBeforeSave()">
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```